# Dynamically adding values to dynamically created vectors

Tags: r

I just started learning to code in R. I have a requirement where I have to keep adding unknown number of values to different vectors (number of vectors is not known).  So, I tried to implement this using -

```
clust_oo = c()
clust_oo[k] = c(clust_oo[k],init_dataset[k,1])
```

Without the `[k]`, the above code works but since i don't know the number of vectors/lists i have to use `[k]` as a differentiator. `clust_oo[1]` could have values say, `1`,`23`,`45` , `clust_oo[2]` could have other values `4`, `40` and `clust_oo[3]` with values `44`, `67`, `455`, `885`. Where the values are added dynamically.

Is this the right way to proceed for this?

Comment: `clust_oo[1]` isn't going to have more than one element unless you're using a list.  Is that what you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
clust_oo = c()

for(i in 1:3) 
      clust_oo[length(clust_oo)+1] = i

clust_oo
[1] 1 2 3
```